# Swap columns in c++

Tags: c++, swap

I have an std matrix defined as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > Qe(6,std::vector<double>(6));
```

and a vector v that is:

```
v{0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
```

I would like to swap the columns 3 and 2 of matrix Qe like indicated in vector v.

In Matlab this is as easy as writing `Qe=Qe(:,v);`

I wonder if there is an easy way other than a for loop to do this in c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Matlab is dedicated for such computations; C++'s `vector` is a low-level primitive. IOW, nothing I know of.

Comment: Is your matrix row-major or column-major? That is to say, is `Qe[0]` the first row or the first column? I hope column, since that's easier ;-)

Comment: No, the columns don't exist as such. All you have is a vector of vectors. You need to implement your own column swapping function. I would also implement a real matrix class.

Comment: hi, @SteveJessop.  I am afraid its row major :(

Comment: @Ceren: yeah, you're completely on your own then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you've implemented this as a vector of vectors, you can use a simple swap:

```
std::swap(Qe[2], Qe[3]);
```

This should have constant complexity. Of course, this will depend on whether you're treating your data as column-major or row-major. If you're going to be swapping columns often, however, you'll want to arrange the data to suit that (i.e., to allow the code above to work).

As far as doing the job without a `for` loop when you're using row-major ordering (the usual for C++), you can technically eliminate the `for` loop (at least from your source code) by using a standard algorithm instead:

```
std::for_each(Qe.begin(), Qe.end(), [](std::vector<double> &v) {std::swap(v[2], v[3]); });
```

This doesn't really change what's actually happening though--it just hides the `for` loop itself inside a standard algorithm. In this case, I'd probably prefer a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto &v : Qe) 
    std::swap(v[2], v[3]);
```

...but I've never been particularly fond of `std::for_each`, and when C++11 added range-based `for` loops, I think that was a superior alternative to the *vast* majority of cases where `std::for_each` *might* previously have been a reasonable possibility (IOW, I've never seen much use for `std::for_each`, and see almost none now).

Comment: Since I have defined my matrix as row major this swapped my 2nd and 3rd rows. But it is useful anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you implement your matrix.

- If you have a vector of columns, you can swap the column references. *O(1)*
- If you have a vector of rows, you need to swap the elements inside each row using a for loop. *O(n)*

`std::vector<std::vector<double>>` can be used as a matrix but you also need to define for yourself whether it is a vector of *columns* or vector of *rows*.

You can create a function for this so you don't write a for loop each time. For example, you can write a function which receives a matrix which is a vector of columns and a reordering vector (like v) and based on the reordering vector you create a new matrix.

```
//untested code and inefficient, just an example:
vector<vector<double>> ReorderColumns(vector<vector<double>> A, vector<int> order)
{
    vector<vector<double>> B;
    for (int i=0; i<order.size(); i++)
    {
        B[i] = A[order[i]];
    }
    return B;
}
```

Edit: If you want to do linear algebra there are libraries that can help you, you don't need to write everything yourself. There are math libraries for other purposes too.

Comment: _I wonder if there is an easy way other than a for loop to do this in c++._

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a row scenario. The following would probably work:

```
// To be tested
std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it;
for (it = Qe.begin(); it != Qe.end(); ++it)
{
    std::swap((it->second)[2], (it->second)[3]);
}
```

In this scenario I don't see any other solution that would avoid doing a loop O(n).